# Why the a tag appearing before the button?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and wondering why the a tag is displaying before the button using the code below?

```
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-header" aria-controls="navbar-header" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
     <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm-up" href="#">My Company</a>
```

Comment: Impossible to say, without seeing the CSS for the elements. But probably there is a `float: right;` or something on the `<a>`. Or something along those lines.

Comment: the css is just bootstrap's 4 no custom css.

Comment: I think its the class `.navbar-brand` that is moving to a tag before the button

Comment: Your navbar brand is positioned to the left by default, I think. Have you tried changing it to the right by adding a class pull-right to the a tag.

Comment: pull-right has no effect on the a tag. navbar-brand seems to override it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, .navbar-brand's default css floats the item to the left

by adding this css, you can move it to the right of the toggle:

```
.navbar-brand {
    float:right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jennift/m507ckb2/